# MySQL - Concatenate Existing Fields in New Generated Field

Tags: mysql, database

In my table, I have two fields: `book` and `reference`. Neither are required to be unique on their own. However, the concatenated value of these two values must be unique.

I'm trying to create a generated column that concatenates the two, but I'm receiving the following error message when running the SQL:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `bibleverses`.`myverses` 
ADD COLUMN `fullref` VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(book, reference)) STORED AFTER `mp3`;

    Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
    ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(book, reference)) STORED AFTER `mp3`' at line 2
    SQL Statement:
    ALTER TABLE `bibleverses`.`myverses` 
    ADD COLUMN `fullref` VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(book, reference)) STORED AFTER `mp3`
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of my current settings.]

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.7 or newer? That's when generated columns were added.

Comment: Running MySQL 5.6.37. I suppose that would be the problem.

Comment: BTW: You don't need a generated column just to make the combination of `(book, reference)` unique. You can define a composite unique key.

Comment: If you want to maintain uniqueness, instead of having a generated column, you can use UNIQUE constraint on combination of book and reference

ALTER TABLE `bibleverses`.`myverses` ADD UNIQUE(`book`, `reference`);

Comment: @PraveenE That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this thing by just applying UNIQUE key constraint to both these columns and it will become a composite key so that you can store the unique values in a pair of these two columns. You can try following SQL statement :

`ALTER TABLE bibleverses.myverses ADD UNIQUE(book, reference);`

Answer (score 0):

First execute an alter table to add your new column, then you run an update to fill out the fild, like:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN <column name, type, definition, etc>;
UPDATE TABLE <table_name> SET <field> = <value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a virtual generated column (which updates if the constituents changes)

`ALTER TABLE` producer`ADD COLUMN`FullName `varchar(32) as (CONCAT(FirstName,' ',Surname));`